# how to calculate the area of different labels and remove the labels with smaller area

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i labeled an image using CC = bwconncomp(BW).now i have to remove labels with smaller area.i have used below code to find an area.

```
[B,L] = bwboundaries(Bw,'noholes');
stats = regionprops(L,'Area','perimeter');
area = [stats.Area];
```

but now how do i remove labels with smaller area???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.  Use [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html).  This takes in a binary image, and a minimum area that you want to enforce.  The output is the same image but with all areas that are below the minimum area being removed.

Therefore, assuming that `thresh` is the minimum area you want to keep for the objects in the image, do:

```
%// Remove those labels that are below an area of thresh
out = bwareaopen(L ~= 0, thresh);

%// Make a copy of the original label matrix and 
%// only copy the labels that appeared in the above result over
Lfinal = zeros(size(L));
Lfinal(out) = L(out);
```

`Lfinal` contains the final label matrix that have the smaller areas removed.  In your case, you may want to eliminate those objects that are less than a certain amount from the object with the maximum area... so perhaps do something like:

```
thresh = round(0.1*max(area));
```

This takes a look at the largest area in your label matrix, and takes 10% of that.  Any objects whose areas are below 10% of this maximum area would be removed from your label matrix.

Comment: thank u its really help full..but i did it in different way. BW2(vertcat((CC.PixelIdxList{cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList)<100})))=0;

Comment: A little more complicated than necessary, but I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: i labeled an image using CC = bwconncomp(BW); and masking the label with maximum area using code

numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
[biggest,idx] = max(numPixels);
BW(CC.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 0;

now i want to put thin rectangular box around that maximum area instead of masking it...how it can be done???
plz help me..to solve this issue..

Comment: @santoshpatil - That's a new question.  Please ask a new one.

Comment: @santoshpatil - I didn't see that.  I'll take a look now.